# How to resolve paths of the glob patterns in the emitted code by TSC?

Tags: node.js, typescript, glob, tsconfig, tsc

**Intro**

My project's file structure is as below:

```
root
├───src
│   ├───index.ts
│   └───docs
│       ├───tags.yaml
│       └───servers.yaml
└───tsconfig.json
```

I am using a node library that needs glob pattern to load the `yaml` files inside `docs` directory. I use the following code in `index.ts` to load the files and it works in the development env (`ts-node --project ./tsconfig.json ./src/index.ts`)
):

```
lib.load({ files: [ './src/docs/*.yaml' ] });
```

**Problem**

Since I have `"rootDir": "./src"` in my tsconfig.json file, the `./src/` path won't work in the emitted code generated by the tsc build.

**What I have tried**

- As you might already know, there are a few workarounds for path resolving issues of the emitted code. such as using `tsconfig-paths` or path aliasing. AFAIK, all these solutions are for package importing and none of these can help resolve a relative path to an absolute path after the tsc build.
  For instance, those are useful when importing packages: `import apiRoutes from '@routes/api.ts'`
- I tried to read almost all the comments in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26722) that seemed the most relevant location to follow such a thing. But unfortunately, I couldn't find anything helpful.
- I could solve my problem by including both paths (before and after the build) to have this working in both `dev` and `prod` environments.

  ```
  lib.load({ files: [ './src/docs/*.yaml', './docs/*.yaml' ] });
  ```

But obviously, the last workaround that I tried is not a reliable solution as it might get complicated when the project grows. Additionally, I want to make sure that I have considered all the possible solutions and different paths that I can take.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.